# What's wrong with this Java code? Android?

Tags: java, android

the purpose of this activity/program is to simply switch from this activity to another one using a button. From IzzynActivity to notes. Here is the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="izzy.n"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name="izzy.n.notes"
                android:label="@string/notes"></activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the IzzynActivity.java code:

```
package izzy.n;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class IzzynActivity extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, notes.class);
                IzzynActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem here?

Comment: where ur getting error, i think u misplaced tags in menifest..

Comment: Im  not getting errors. Just when i run it on my phone and i click on the button no new activity happends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `activity` cannot contain another `activity` in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Here's the right code:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.notes"
            android:label="@string/notes"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Note:**

If you return anything with `setResult()` from a started activity you should start it using `startActivityForResult`.

**For the warning message:**

Just edit one piece of code and re-run your application. It will be reinstalled on the phone and you should not see the warning message again.

Comment: Check the LogCat. Does it say anything weird when you press the button?

Comment: izzyn] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=izzy.n/.IzzynActivity }
[2012-02-29 02:28:40 - izzyn] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: public class notes extends Activity{
 
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes);

        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
     }
        
    });
   }
}

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781182/activity-not-started-its-current-task-has-been-brought-to-the-front

Comment: Everything runs fine,until i actually ask for it to go to a diff xml page

Comment: Just edit one piece of code and re-run your application. It will be reinstalled on the phone and you should not see the warning message again.

Comment: Nothing changed, but thanks! Ill try to get to it in the morning thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For one you have an activity tag inside another activity tag in your manifest which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`</activity>` closing tag for your first activity should come before starting tag for your second activity. You are nesting your activities, which is not permitted.

Comment: <activity
                android:name="izzy.n.notes"
                android:label="@string/notes"></activity>  u mean this?

Comment: Nesting of activities is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="izzy.n"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".notes"
                android:label="@string/notes">
        </activity>

    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name="izzy.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name="izzy.n.notes"
                android:label="@string/notes"></activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

you are declareing an activity inside another activity without closing first one: so replace this block with:

```
<activity
            android:name="izzy.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
                android:name="izzy.n.notes"
                android:label="@string/notes"></activity>
            <intent-filter>
```

Comment: Even after the fix the button isnt working, is it possible maybe something else?