# Android DDMS activityManager

Tags: java, android, ddms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781182/activity-not-started-its-current-task-has-been-brought-to-the-front)

Why does this error appear when i am launching my application ??

```
[2012-06-16 14:13:17 - Cameraaaa] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Comment: can you explain what did you mean ???

Comment: I think its explained there on the link more clearly.mind taking a look on relevant questions first?

Comment: @Mahmudemam : it means just close your application from device then try it to run

Comment: "lunching" - The verb-version of "lunch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this comes up when your current deployment on the device is the same as the one you are trying to install now, when launching from eclipse