# Activity not started : Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-emulator, activity-manager

I was trying to run my application on Eclipse and I received this message on the LogCat (Might be due to a problem in the android emulator)

" ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Just to mention that it was working fine and that i didn't change anything in my code

Moreover a lot of times the emulator doesn't load the content knowing that i have no error in the LogCat

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781182/activity-not-started-its-current-task-has-been-brought-to-the-front

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer :

It is not an error message, it is a warning. What the system is trying to tell you: The application on the device is the same as your application in Eclipse. And because the application is already running on the device, the system tells you that it is not going to kill and restart it, but bring the activity of your already running app into the foreground. This is pretty normal. ;-)

The warning will not continue if you edit your code and run it (because the app is then killed, reinstalled and started) or if you kill your process on the phone, e.g. via the DDMS.