# How Solve Activity not started in Android DeepLink?

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking

I am working on DeepLink on Android. So, I add in my AndroidManifest this code:

```
<activity android:name=".Home"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/config"
                android:pathPrefix="/newslist/"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="*XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/config"
                android:path="/newslist/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then I add this codes in Home.class:

```
    finish();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String intentData = intent.getDataString();
    if (intentData != null && Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        fragment = new FragmentNews();
        imageViewHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewFragmentName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewFragmentName.setText("News");
    }
```

Then, I want to test for DeepLink. I use Android Studio terminal and run this line:

```
C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/config/newslist
```

But, when I run this code I receive an error:

> "Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to
>   the front"

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it will help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781182/activity-not-started-its-current-task-has-been-brought-to-the-front

Comment: @AjayaTiwari, thank you. When I kill app in phone, I don't take this error.

Comment: if it's working please add as useful.